# How to stop flipping the text when flipping the frame in cv2

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to make an app that can recognize face, eyes and the smile.
But everything is working good except the text on the box which is created when smiling. Because when I flipped the frame (frame that capture by 1cv2.VideoCapture(0)`), the text is also flipped.
How can I stop it? Any help please....

Here is my code,

```
import cv2
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_eye.xml")
smile_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_smile.xml")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    fsced = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x, y, w, h) in fsced:
        center_cordinates = x + w // 2, y + h // 2
        radius = w // 2
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
        roi_gray = gray[y : y + h, x : x +w]
        roi_colour = img[y : y + h, x : x +w]
        smiles = smile_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray, 1.8, 20)
        for (sx, sy, sw, sh) in smiles:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_colour, (sx, sy), ((sx + sw), (sy + sh)), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.putText(roi_colour, "Smile", (sx, sy), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
        center_cordinates_eye = ex + ew // 2, ey + eh // 2
        radius_eye = w // 10
        cv2.circle(img, center_cordinates_eye, radius_eye, (5, 50, 10), thickness=2, lineType=8, shift=0)


    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyWindow('img')
```

In this code you can see the text `"Smile"`. when I run the code, this text will flip.

I tried changing the text after the flipping, But nothing good.
Like this,

```
Text = "" # This Text = "" is at the start of the code
"""
Other code
"""
img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
Text = "Smile"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the moment when you do:

```py
            cv2.putText(roi_colour, "Smile", (sx, sy), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

You "melt" the text into the image, you cannot modify it per se after that.

Regarding:
*I tried changing the text after the flipping, But nothing good. Like this,*
What you did was you actually changed the value of the string "Text", you can print it below, it is indeed changed, but the `np.array/openCV image` is not.

You can however gather the coordinates for the text into a list let's say and then in a loop add the text after the flipping.

```
smiles_coordinates = []
for (sx, sy, sw, sh) in smiles:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_colour, (sx, sy), ((sx + sw), (sy + sh)), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            smiles_coordinates.append((sx,sy)) # Here the "sy" is probably fine, but figure out correct "sx" as a homework
```

And then after the `flip`

```py
for (sx, sy) in smile_coordinates:
 cv2.putText(roi_colour, "Smile", (sx, sy), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
```